# Помощь с перестановкой местами элементов списка. C#

Tags: c#, list

*Дан односвязный линейный список и целое число n. Элемент списка содержит следующую информацию: фамилия студента, шифр группы. Требуется сдвинуть циклически элементы на n позиций: удалять элементы с конца списка и добавлять их в начало списка.*
Не могу выполнить последнюю часть задачи, пытался менять значения элементов с помощью дополнительной переменной, но возникли сложности с дальнейшим пониманием действий

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Лабораторная_работа__Односвязные_списки_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student k = null; string d;
            Console.WriteLine($"Введите кол-во интераций");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            List<student> info = new List<student>(2);
            Console.WriteLine($"Введите кол-во студентов");
            int kol = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < kol; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Введите инфо о студенте");
                info.Add(new student() { data = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()) });
                k = info[kol];

            }
            Console.WriteLine(k);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                info.Add(k);
                info.RemoveAt(kol);
                k = info[kol - 1];
            }

            foreach (student p in info)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.data);
            }
        }
    }
    class student
    {
        public string data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<student>` - это не односвязный список.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }

    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

    public Node(T d)
    { 
        Data = d; 
        Next = default; 
    }
}

public class LinkList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private Node<T> _head;

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public bool IsEmpty => Count == 0;

    public void LastToFirst(int iteration) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++)
            LastToFirst();
    }

    public void LastToFirst()
    {
        if (_head == null || _head.Next == null)
            return;

        Node<T> secLast = default;
        Node<T> last = _head;
        while (last.Next != null)
        {
            secLast = last;
            last = last.Next;
        }
        secLast.Next = null;
        last.Next = _head;
        _head = last;
    }

    public bool SaveOnlyLast()
    {
        if (_head == null)
            return false;

        var remove = _head;
        while (remove.Next != null)
            remove = remove.Next;

        remove.Next = null;
        _head = remove;
        Count = 1;
        return true;
    }

    public bool RemoveLast()
    {
        if (_head == null && _head.Next == null)
            return false;

        Node<T> second_last = _head;
        while (second_last.Next.Next != null)
            second_last = second_last.Next;

        second_last.Next = null;
        Count--;
        return true;
    }

    public Node<T> Add(T item)
    {
        if (_head == null)
        {
            _head = CreateNode(item);
            Count++;
            return _head;
        }

        if (_head.Next == null)
        { 
            _head.Next = CreateNode(item);
            Count++;
            return _head.Next;
        }

        Node<T> second_last = _head;
        while (second_last.Next.Next != null)
            second_last = second_last.Next;

        second_last.Next.Next = CreateNode(item);
        Count++;
        return second_last.Next.Next;
    }

    public void PrintList()
    {
        Node<T> temp = _head;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            Console.Write(temp.Data + " ");
            temp = temp.Next;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _head = null;
        Count = 0;
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        Node<T> current = _head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Data.Equals(item))
                return true;
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Node<T> Push(T item)
    {
        Node<T> new_node = new Node<T>(item)
        {
            Next = _head
        };
        _head = new_node;
        Count++;

        return new_node;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Node<T> current = _head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() =>
        ((IEnumerable)this).GetEnumerator();

    private Node<T> CreateNode(T item)
        => new Node<T>(item) { Next = default };
}
```

Использование:

```
LinkList<int> l = new LinkList<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    l.Add(i);

l.PrintList();

l.LastToFirst();
l.PrintList();

l.LastToFirst(2);
l.PrintList();

l.RemoveLast();
l.PrintList();

l.Push(55);
l.PrintList();

l.RemoveLast();
l.PrintList();

l.Add(101);
l.PrintList();

Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: https://pastenow.ru/GXXX5]

Comment: Отлично, только здесь тоже нет односвязного списка.

Comment: @aepot Исправлено. Не заметил, что нужно односвязанный лист использовать. Увидел по коду, что используется обычный лист, поэтому и сделал изначально через него

Comment: `LinkedList<T>` - это друхсвязный список.

Comment: Исправил. Сейчас связь только одна

Comment: `IDisposable` - лишнее усложнение.